# Difference between Constraints and Rules in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, constraints, business-rules

What is the difference between using **constraints** and **rules** in SQL, preferably SQL server 2008 R2. Can anyone explain and demonstrate with a real time example

Comment: Don't forget that rules are obsolete - see [create rule in Sql Server 2012](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188064.aspx).

Comment: Still unclear to you?

Comment: @NikolaMarkovinović - although there is a 'may remove' warning from 2017, it's in SQL2019 so it is still available in new current versions of MySQL.

Answer (score 6):

There are a lot of difference but 
One the most notable difference is that we can bind rules to a datatypes whereas constraints are bound only to columns.
 this feature enable us to create our own data-type with the help of Rules and get the input according to that.

I have found a good example, check the following link.
[constraints vs rules](http://sybasease.blogspot.com/2005/08/constraints-vs-rules.html)

Answer (score 1):

From Postgres manual:

> The PostgreSQL rule system allows one to define an alternate action to be performed on insertions, updates, or deletions in database tables. Roughly speaking, a rule causes additional commands to be executed when a given command on a given table is executed

A constraint, as an example, can be used to ensure that a given number never matches some value. Such a birth year should not be under 1880 for new users registering or above the current year.

Answer (score 0):

I would add some differences

1) rules are reusables , so one time you make a rule you can be bound to one or more columns. 
2) in the other hand, Constrains :
   - single column can have several constrainst.
   - message can be bound to  constraints
 constrains are normaly created in the "create table statmen" or with a "alter table add constraint "

cheers

Answer (score 0):

> In short:

`Rules` is a feature that executes some validation functions based on some other data or systems.

`CHECK constraint` is used to restrict the values in a column to allow only if it meets the condition based on this particular value.

> See this article for possible helpful information:

[Difference between Constraints and Rules in SQL](https://www.codeproject.com/Questions/609687/DifferenceplusbetweenplusConstraintsplusandplusRul)